# How can I use LTSPICE to store outputs of a circuit and use it later?

Tags: ltspice, simulation, memory, synthesis, memristor

I am using Ltspice simulator to simulate an algorithm in which I will have to store the output of circuit and use it later in the circuit. But not able to use memory in ltspice for the same.
Please suggest any ways/tool/process etc.

Thank you.

Comment: In case you are asking this in order to compare different component values, a simpler way is via the .step command which will plot all the results together. .step can be also used to connect/disconnect some parts of the circuit (by stepping a resistor from e.g. 1m to 1G)

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question. There are also behavioral sources which reference a different net in your circuit, so they use it as an input. But I'm not sure if you mean the same circuit when you write "store the output of circuit and use it later in the circuit"

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK ltspice can't directly reopen it's own output, at least from the job cards. However you should be able to export the waveform from the GUI and reimport that as a source with the .wave card.

More info here

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/ltspice-simulation-using-wav-files/

Comment: your reply is useful to me. Thank you. Can you please tell me how we could perform time operation on a signal in ltspice simulator?

Answer (score 1):

If the already existent comments and answer don't do it then you're probably referring to `.savebias` and `.loadbias` commands. See the help under *LTspice > Dot Commands > .[LOAD/SAVE]BIAS*:

> This command writes a text file to disk that is reloaded with a .loadbias command in a subsequent simulation. If you have a circuit that has a difficult-to-solve DC operating point, you can save that solution to disk so that the next analysis can save time finding the DC solution before proceeding to the rest of the simulation.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the graphical simulation output, you will get a fly-out menu. Choose *File > Export data as text*. You have the option of choosing which nodes to save.